# Should this question be migrated instead of closed?

Tags: discussion, migration

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24024405/blue-screen-of-death) obviously doesn't belong here, and would probably be shot down if it were migrated to Super User. Still, shouldn't it be sent there rather than being closed as off topic?

The question is a BSOD help question.

Answer (score 9):

It's not of sufficient quality to be migrated.

Questions should only be migrated when it is clear that the target site will benefit from the question and its quality.

> i have my computer for 3 months already and i already had BSOD 3
>   times, 2 of the were today
>
> could you please help me figure out what my problem is?
>
> here are the zipped dump files:
>
> https://www.dropbox.com/s/wbg8g43s4lax54t/mindump.zip
>
> these are my systems' tech specs:
>
> intel core i7 4770
>
> gigabyte ultra durable 4 motherboard
>
> 16gb of ram
>
> gainward nvidia geforce gtx 760 with 4gb of dedicated video ram
>
> Thank you very much

Comment: Ok, so migrations only happen with good questions. Thanks for clarifying.